# critiria to prove that a morphism is an embedding

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, coarse-moduli-spaces

I have a forgetful map between moduli spaces, I want to prove that it is an embedding, In fact, I have a reductive algebric group (which is not constant) over a curve $X$ whose geniric fiber is semisimple.
And I have a forgetful map from $Bun_\mathcal G$ to the algebraic stuck of vector bundle $\mathscr   {SL}(r)$

Is there any usuful critiria in this situation?

Comment: Does this forgetful morphism arise from a faithful morphism of $X$-group schemes, $\mathcal{G} \to \textbf{SL}_{r,X}$?  If so, for a fixed $\textbf{SL}_{r,X}$-torsor $E$, the "reductions of structure group" to $\mathcal{G}$ are naturally in bijection with sections of the associated affine morphism $E/\mathcal{G} \to X$.

Comment: I am not sure if that morphism is faithfull or not, but even we suppose so, I don't see your response, could you please explain a litte bit?